# Why is assignment of Double to Single allowed with Option Strict On

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Why doesn't the following code cause a compile error, even though I have `Option Strict On`?

```
Dim value As Single = 12345.12345  ' No error
```

The numeric literal is, by default, interpreted by the compiler as a `Double`.  Converting from `Double` to `Single` is a narrowing conversion (the assignment, in this case, actually rounds the value to `12345.123`).  According to the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs(v=vs.100).aspx), `Option Strict On` has the following effect:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

Based on that description, my example code should cause an error.  In fact, even if I explicitly specify the type character after the literal, it still doesn't see it as an error:

```
Dim value As Single = 12345.12345R   'Still no error, despite the "R"
```

Even this doesn't cause an error:

```
Dim value As Single = CDbl(12345.12345)   'Still no error, despite the CDbl() conversion
```

But, this does cause an error, as I'd expect:

```
Dim value1 As Double = 12345.12345
Dim value2 As Single = value1    ' Causes "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Single'" error
```

Similarly, this also fails, as expected:

```
Public Function GetValue() As Double
    Return 12345.12345
End Function

' ...

Dim value As Single = GetValue()   ' Causes "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Single'" error
```

As a side note, the following fails in C#, as expected:

```cs
float x = 12345.12345;  ' Causes error in C#
```

So, it's not a problem with all .NET languages.  It just seems to be a peculiarity of VB.NET.

Also, VB.NET doesn't allow this implicit conversion, even though it is converting from a literal:

```
Dim x As Integer = 1.5  ' Causes error
```

So, my question is, why does VB.NET work this way?  It seems like a flaw to me, but maybe there is some good explanation as to why it allows narrowing conversions of `Double` literals to `Single`, but not in any other situation.

Comment: "*The numeric literal is, by default, interpreted by the compiler as a Double.*"  Are you sure that's true?  Do you have a reference for that? Because I would have assumed that it was interpreted as a Single, as historically, that's how prior incarnations of VB/Basic have done it.  (which is why I write such things with a "#" appended.)

Comment: OK, according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzy06xhf.aspx you are correct ...

Comment: Very strange! This also works without complaints: Dim value As Single = Double.MaxValue as well as Double.PositiveInfinity etc

Comment: This seems like a compiler bug based on the question and comments...

Comment: This has the common answer: "because the language specification says it is valid".  Section 11.2: "These narrowing conversions are allowed regardless of whether permissive or strict semantics are being used."

Comment: @HansPassant Wow.  Yeah, the end of that section couldn't be any more clear.  That's strange that they single out just the `Double` type in the specification like that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hans has pointed out in the comments above, the [VB.NET language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050(v=vs.71).aspx) is very clear on this topic.  In [section 11.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712020(v=vs.71).aspx), it clearly states:

> Constant expressions of an integral type (`Long`, `Integer`, `Short`, `Byte`) can be implicitly converted to a narrower integral type, and constant expressions of type `Double` can be implicitly converted to `Single`, provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type. These narrowing conversions are allowed regardless of whether permissive or strict semantics are being used.

Since this behavior is dictated by the specification, it is obviously by design.  As long as `Double` value is a constant, the implicit conversion to `Single` is always allowed, even if the conversion causes the value to lose precision.  The bit about "*provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type*" is misleading in this case.  The `Single` type supports representing values of negative infinity and positive infinity, so when a `Double` value is outside of the valid range of the `Single` type, it just sets it to one of those infinity values.

As far as the rationale behind the design decision for this behavior, I can't say for sure, but I suspect it's to allow for more convenient syntax like this:

```
Dim x As Single = 1 / 2
```

If `Option Strict On` disallowed the implicit conversion from `Double` to `Single`, you'd be forced to always write something as simple as that like this:

```
Dim x As Single = 1.0F / 2.0F
```

Or

```
Dim x As Single = CSng(1 / 2)
```

Which, in my mind, would arguably be preferable, but I can understand why the language designers would decide that the syntax of that would be too confusing.

Comment: It does still leave the question of why Dim value as Single = Double.MaxValue works as Double.MaxValue is not within the range of a Single.

Comment: @theduck True.  In fact, `Dim x As Single = 1E+300` works, even though that's way out of range for a `Single`.  So, apparently either my interpretation of the meaning of that section is incorrect, or else the compiler is missing the mark slightly...

Comment: @theduck Read the last part of section 8.3: For a conversion from Double to Single, the Double value is rounded to the nearest Single value. If the Double value is too small to represent as a Single, the result becomes positive zero or negative zero. If the Double value is too large to represent as a Single, the result becomes positive infinity or negative infinity. If the Double value is NaN, the result is also NaN.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå right, so when it says in 11.2 *"provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type"*, it must be referring to constants of all integral types rather than just `Double` to `Single`.  It's just imprecisely worded since it could be easily read either way.

Comment: @StevenDoggart English is not my native language, but that's how I read it. And I agree it's a bit vague.

Comment: Semantically, quietly accepting something like `single1 = single2 * 0.1;` would be unlikely to yield an unacceptable result.  On the other hand, the code would likely be a fair bit slower than the almost-equivalent `single1 = single2 * 0.1f;` which would in most cases be just as acceptable.  If the programmer writes `single1 = csng(single2 * 0.1);` that would suggest the programmer judged that the extra computational effort was needed; if `single1 = single2 * 0.1f;` that would indicate the sloppier precision of the faster computation was acceptable.  Having the programmer specify...

Comment: ...such things is better than having the compiler "guess".  If the values in question are constants, however, the only "computational effort" would be a single floating-point operation within the compiler, whose cost would be far below that of generating an error message.