# SelectedIndexChanged Event not available in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012, and I am working on a Windows Forms Application. While working with the datagrid view, the `selectedIndexChanged` Event is not available in the list of available events. How can I implement this event?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2u41.png)

Comment: This by yours truly... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280864/what-makes-it-so-that-not-every-event-is-available-in-the-designer-and-how-can

Comment: Its because it doesn't have `SelectedIndexChanged` event. What's your requirement? Do you need [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event?

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no such event in a DataGridView. You can search the msdn help. Use SelectionChanged event instead.

Comment: This answer needs improvement.  As it stands, it's a low quality answer that will probably be deleted.

Comment: @roryap: Not only it is an acceptable answer, it answers and solves the question of the OP. Why do you say that?